# HTML5 canvas scroll-based animation engaging and disengaging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to achieve [this effect](http://ekragency.com/demos/canvas-scroll/) using [this tutorial](http://ekragency.com/canvas-based-scroll-controlled-backgroud-video-use-parallax-style-web-design/) to dynamically add on images from a collection to a canvas to give the appearance of animation as you scroll past the canvas. There are three divs on the page top to bottom: div_1 is a full page static image, div_2 is the canvas, and div_3 is a full-page static image. After scrolling past div_1, the desired behavior is: 
 
- Once div_1 is out of view, the scrolling action of the mouse/trackpad would cease scrolling down the page 
- pause over div_2/canvas 
- the mouse/trackpad would begin cycling through all of the images (displayed via the canvas) in the collection until the last image is displayed 
- the scrolling action would resume to continue down the page to div_3.

I cannot figure out how to engage/disengage the mouseWheel event that I am tying into; from the very top of the page it's (understandably) tied into cycling the images, but I can't figure out a way to trigger it once div_1 is out of view and then disengage it once the scroll-based animation has completed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**html.erb**

```
<body>

  <div class="div_1">
    <!-- Full screen image to  scroll past -->
  </div>

  <div class="div_2">
    <canvas id="background" width="1280" height="720"></canvas>
  </div>

  <div class="div_3">
    <!-- Full screen image to scroll to once animation is complete -->
  </div>

</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
var totalImages = IMAGE_URLS.length; 
var images = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < totalImages; i++) {
    var img = new Image;
    img.src = IMAGE_URLS[i];
    images.push(img);
}


var currentLocation = 0;
var canv;
var context;
$(document).ready(function(){
  canv = document.getElementById('background');
  context = canv.getContext('2d');
  mouseWheel();

  // See above for where this gets called

});

var mouseWheel = function() {
  window.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // No scroll

    // The following equation will return either a 1 for scroll down
    // or -1 for a scroll up
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, e.wheelDelta));

    // This code mostly keeps us from going too far in either direction
    if(delta == -1) currentLocation += .5;
    if(delta == 1) currentLocation -= .5`;
    if(currentLocation < 0) currentLocation = 0;
    if(currentLocation > images.length)
      currentLocation = images.length;

    // See below for the details of this function
    setImage(currentLocation);
  });
}

var setImage = function(newLocation) {
    // drawImage takes 5 arguments: image, x, y, width, height
    context.drawImage(images[newLocation], 0, 0, 1280, 720);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "engage/disengage" ? Do you want the event handler to have no effect anymore? then have a look to [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). But if you simply want it to do an action if the current scroll position is x and an other action if it is y then have a look to [if statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: Could you not just have all the images in the canvas and remove `div_1` and `div_3`? No need to use the divs if you just want to scroll through a collection of images via a canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jvLk0vhp/1/

javascript :

```
var images = new Array();
var currentLocation = 0;
var totalImages = 7;

for (var i = 0; i < totalImages; i++) {
    var img = new Image;
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            img.src = "http://img.pokemondb.net/sprites/black-white/normal/mewtwo.png";
            break;
        case 1:
            img.src = "http://img.pokemondb.net/sprites/black-white/normal/keldeo-ordinary.png";
            break;
        case 2:
            img.src = "http://img.pokemondb.net/sprites/black-white/normal/darkrai.png";
            break;
        case 3:
            img.src = "http://floatzel.net/pokemon/black-white/sprites/images/5.png";
            break;
        case 4:
            img.src = "http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/capx/images/0/03/001.png/revision/latest?cb=20140322003659";
            break;
        case 5:
            img.src = "http://img.pokemondb.net/sprites/black-white/normal/absol.png";
            break;
        case 6:
            img.src = "http://img.pokemondb.net/sprites/black-white/normal/dewgong.png";
            break;
        case 7:
            img.src = "http://orig05.deviantart.net/e770/f/2013/008/c/6/froakie_by_baconboy914-d5qvrjo.gif";
            break;
    }

    images.push(img);
}

var c = document.getElementById("background");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var mouseWheel = function () {
    window.addEventListener('mousewheel', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // No scroll

        // The following equation will return either a 1 for scroll down
        // or -1 for a scroll up
        var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, e.wheelDelta));

        // This code mostly keeps us from going too far in either direction
        if (delta == -1) currentLocation += 1;
        if (delta == 1) currentLocation -= 1;
        if (currentLocation < 0) currentLocation = 0;
        if (currentLocation >= (totalImages - 1)) currentLocation = (totalImages - 1);
        console.log("Current location " + currentLocation);

        // See below for the details of this function
        setImage(currentLocation);
    });
}

var setImage = function (newLocation) {
    // drawImage takes 5 arguments: image, x, y, width, height
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.drawImage(images[newLocation], 0, 0, 150, 150);
}

images[0].onload = function () {
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.drawImage(images[currentLocation], 0, 0, 150, 150);
    mouseWheel();
};
```

I have just used a canvas to achieve the expected output, if you still want to use a div for the first and last check my second answer below

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jvLk0vhp/2/

javascript (also using divs)

```
var images = new Array();
var currentLocation = 0;
var totalImages = 7;
var div1 = document.getElementById("id_1");
var div2 = document.getElementById("id_2");
var div3 = document.getElementById("id_3");

div2.style.display = "none";
div3.style.display = "none";

for (var i = 0; i < totalImages; i++) {
    var img = new Image;
    switch (i) {
        case 1:
            img.src = "http://img.pokemondb.net/sprites/black-white/normal/keldeo-ordinary.png";
            break;
        case 2:
            img.src = "http://img.pokemondb.net/sprites/black-white/normal/darkrai.png";
            break;
        case 3:
            img.src = "http://floatzel.net/pokemon/black-white/sprites/images/5.png";
            break;
        case 4:
            img.src = "http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/capx/images/0/03/001.png/revision/latest?cb=20140322003659";
            break;
        case 5:
            img.src = "http://img.pokemondb.net/sprites/black-white/normal/absol.png";
            break;
        case 6:
            img.src = "http://img.pokemondb.net/sprites/black-white/normal/dewgong.png";
            break;
    }

    images.push(img);
}

var c = document.getElementById("background");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var mouseWheel = function () {
    window.addEventListener('mousewheel', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // No scroll

        // The following equation will return either a 1 for scroll down
        // or -1 for a scroll up
        var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, e.wheelDelta));

        // This code mostly keeps us from going too far in either direction
        if (delta == -1) currentLocation += 1;
        if (delta == 1) currentLocation -= 1;
        if (currentLocation < 0) currentLocation = 0;
        if (currentLocation >= (totalImages - 1)) currentLocation = (totalImages - 1);
        console.log("Current location " + currentLocation);

        // See below for the details of this function
        setImage(currentLocation);
    });
}

var setImage = function (newLocation) {
    // drawImage takes 5 arguments: image, x, y, width, height
    if (newLocation == 0) {
        div1.style.display = "block";
        div2.style.display = "none";
        div3.style.display = "none";
    } else if (newLocation == (totalImages - 1)) {
        div1.style.display = "none";
        div2.style.display = "none";
        div3.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        div1.style.display = "none";
        div2.style.display = "block";
        div3.style.display = "none";

        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        ctx.drawImage(images[newLocation], 0, 0, 150, 150);
    }
}


ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
ctx.drawImage(images[currentLocation], 0, 0, 150, 150);
mouseWheel();
```